# Disable checkbox if value selected

Tags: jquery, checkbox, dropdown

I need a short jQuery code to do the following.

I got a dropdown like this:

```
<select id="pa_size">
    <option value="32cm">32 cm</option>
    <option value="52cm">52 cm</option>
</select>
```

And some other checkboxes under that dropdown.

**Now my problem is:** 
I want to disable the checkboxes IF the 52 cm option is selected. 
By default the checkboxes are enabled, and if returned to 32cm from 52cm it should be working again.

Comment: share complete html

Comment: please update your question and give full html template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML

```
<select id="worldSelect" class="select" name="world">
<option value="32cm">32 cm</option>
<option value="52cm">52 cm</option>
</select>
<input id="worldcb" type="checkbox" checked value="any" name="world">
```

Script

```
 $('#worldSelect').change(function () {
    $(':checkbox').prop('disabled', this.value == '52cm');
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `prop()` method like following.

```js
$('#pa_size').change(function () {
    $(':checkbox').prop('disabled', this.value == '52cm');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pa_size">
    <option value="32cm">32 cm</option>
    <option value="52cm">52 cm</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following html code:

```
<select id="pa_size">
  <option value="32cm">32 cm</option>
  <option value="52cm">52 cm</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" class="todisable"  value="1"> chbx1
<input type="checkbox" class="todisable" value="2"> chbx2
<input type="checkbox" class="todisable" value="3"> chbx3
```

And also see the following javascript code:

```
$("#pa_size").on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "52cm") {
     $(".todisable").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  } else {
     $(".todisable").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
});
```

If you want to test it running on fiddle click [here](https://jsfiddle.net/e02oh64x/):